# ARMV 7 Duplication ERROR

Tags: xcode, cordova, urbanairship.com, armv7

**iOS Phonegap and Urban Airship Implementation// duplicate symbols for armv7**

Instructions are given by Urban Airship to implement the Push Notifications. https://docs.urbanairship.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started%3A+iOS%3A+Push

But when the build process is taking place an error occurs.

> Link/Users/Addd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/hello-asidjfhsalkdfjnslfdkjsadf/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/hello.app/hello
>
> 586 Duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 Linker Command failed
>   with exit code 1(use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 4):

There are two files in the downloaded source: **libUAirship-3.0.1.a** and **libUAirship-iOS5-3.0.1.a**. You will need only the appropriate one - delete the other.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that libUAirship-3.0.1.a includes armv7/armv7s/arm64/i386/x86_64 versions, aka 32 and 64-bit binaries and will run on iOS5.1.1+, while libUAirship-iOS5-x.y.z.a is a 32-bit only package if you need to run on iOS5.0 (see https://github.com/urbanairship/ios-library for more details).